# Way of beheading before consuming meat

Tags: animals, food

In north part of India, I have observed, Hindus only eat meat of goat/chicken beheaded at once. They say it "jhatakA"; literal meaning "at once". Is this concept backed up by scriptures ? If not then what way is prescribed to behead animal before consuming it ?

Comment: I think it is prescribed to not eat any animals in the scriptures.

Answer (score 9):

Even if one beheads the animal in one go still it will be an act of just a killing and not a sacrifice.

If sacrifice is being performed as per scriptures then first the animal is to be bathed then it has to be worshipped duly thinking it to be Lord Shiva.

The sacrificial post ([the yup](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=yup&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3)), the weapon are to be worshipped too. Otherwise the act is nothing but what happens in slaughterhouses.

Lord Shiva warns in this regard:

> HanyAn-mantrena chAnena tvabhi-mantrya pashum priye |
>   Gandha-pushpa-akshateih pujya chAnyathA narakam vrajet ||
>
> O Beloved, the animal is to be energized with this mantra and then
>   worshipped duly with scents, flowers and rice grains before the
>   sacrifice is being performed. Doing otherwise one will have to visit
>   hell.
>
> *KulArnava Tantram 5.50*

The mantra being talked about is the following:

> Shivotkrittamidam pindam-tastvam shivatAm gatam |
>  Tadvudhyasva
>   pasho tvam hi mAshivas-tvam shivohasi hi ||
>
> Your body will be cut by Shiva; hence you will attain Shiva-hood. O
>   Pashu, know this -- You are not a-Shiva, you are also Shiva.
>
> *5.51*

This is a Bali mantra and the sacrifice is to be performed while chanting it.

So, if these or such instructions are not duly followed then it is just an act of killing an innocent animal. It does no good to anybody and it is not a sacrifice.

The meat is also not sacrificial meat (because it is not a sacrifice and more so because it is not offered to any deity).

In Hinduism, eating meat is not completely disallowed but the recommended method is to offer the meat to deities before eating. Eating sacrificial meat is completely allowed and it has no sins attached to it.

In this regard, see what Lord Shiva says:

> Pitridevatayajneshu VaidahimsA Vidhiyate |
>  AtmArtham PrAninAm
>   HimsA kadAchinnoditA Priye ||
>
> In Yajnas meant for Devas and Pitrus (ancestors) sacrificial killing
>   is allowed. But other than that the Shastras never allow prani himsa
>   (killing) for one's own pleasure.
>
> *KulArnava Tantram, Chapter 5, Verse 45.*

Even if the animal is beheaded in one go it's still not a sacrifice it's just an act of mere killing.

Comment: Good answer! However I am also interested in knowing how to behead animal before consuming meat in general life.

Comment: Such information will not be found in scriptures .. scriptures will only describe the process of pashubali and it will involve worship, mantra etc .. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: Why not ? Don't we chant Bhojan Mantra before consuming food in general life ? I think consuming meat can't be an exception. There should be a way otherwise why in north it is practiced to eat only "jhatakA" meat not halal.

Comment: I think what you are talking about are Muslim practices not Hindu ..anyways you can wait to see what others have to answer.. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: "I think what you are talking about are Muslim practices not Hindu"; By this statement, can it imply that we have no such step of beheading and can consume meat which is beheaded from any method ?

Comment: I don't understand what u mean by "can be eaten" .. ofcourse anyone can eat anything .. scriptures won't recommend meat eating that was not first offered to some deities in sacrifice and if meat is to be sacrificed then methods like I have given must be followed .. otherwise it's just slaughtering .. and Hindu scriptures won't deal with slaughtering .. of course meat eating (outside of rituals) is not disallowed but not recommended either @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: So only sacrificial one should be consumed, otherwise at any circumstances meat eating is discouraged. Right ?

Comment: Yes it is discouraged but not disallowed .. God knows that people will consume no matter what .. because the attraction seems to be great for some reasons @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: Yeah you're right.

Comment: @rickross Good answer

Comment: @PravinRGMishra Thanks ...